# Why does the Android no disturb mode says that only some calls and messages are allowed even though I thought I allowed all calls and messages?

Tags: notifications, sms, calls, android-13, do-not-disturb

I thought I configured Android no disturb mode so that I would be notified of any calls and messages I may receive:

[image: IMG:]

However, it says that only "some calls and messages" are allowed:

[image: IMG:]

Why?